# Unhandled exception at 0x00381977 in Lab_2.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero

Tags: c++

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;

a *= d; 
d /= a; 
a /= d;
    printf("%d %d ", a, d);

    b *= c; //[6; 2]
    c /= b; //[6; 3]
    b /= c;//[2; 3]
    printf("%d %d ", b, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;

a *= d;            // a = 4
d /= a;            // d = 1
a /= d;            // a = 4
printf("%d %d ", a, d);

b *= c; //[6; 2]    // b = 6
c /= b; //[6; 3]    // с = 0 !!!!!!
b /= c;//[2; 3]     //  ДЕЛЕНИЕ НА НОЛЬ!!!!
printf("%d %d ", b, c);
```

Все понятно?

Answer (score 1):

а что вы хотели?

`a *= d` = 1 * 4 = 4

`d /= a` = 4 / 4 = 1

`a /= d` = 4 / 1 = 4

`b *= c` = 2 * 3 = 6

`c /= b` = 3 / 6 = 0 - ведь у нас только целые числа и деление тоже целочисленное

`b /= c` = 6 / 0 - и вот тут ошибка деления на ноль и вылезает